# Tailwind utility classes only working in css file and not inline

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm using **electron**, **react (web)**, **typescript** and **tailwind**.
Now, currently I'm facing the problem that tailwind only works in `.css` files but not inline. See example below

**In .css file** (works)

```
.navbar {
    @apply border-2 border-red-900;
}
```

In `.tsx` file

```
<div className="navbar">
    </div>
```

**Just in .tsx** (does not work)

```js
<div className="border-2 border-red-900">
</div>
```

My `tailwind.config.js` has `content` defined correctly:

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js, jsx, ts, tsx}", "./public/index.html"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Further, when compiling, I get the following warning:

> no utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is
> unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS
> configurat

And `index.css` has following included:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following tailwind [content-configuration](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#configuring-source-paths)

> Tailwind CSS works by scanning all of your HTML, JavaScript components, and any other template files for class names, then generating all of the corresponding CSS for those styles.

> In order for Tailwind to generate all of the CSS you need, it needs to know about every single file in your project that contains any Tailwind class names

- Use * to match anything except slashes and hidden files
- Use ** to match zero or more directories
- Use comma separate values between {} to match against a list of options

Suspectedly your `content` config path is wrong, so double check the path to make sure it scan all source files contain **Tailwind** class names.

Comment: I did't have a Tailwind class in my new code yet and search and search...  The last sentence saved me today. Thank you

Answer (score -2):

you should add this into public/index.html file

```
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```