# Tailwind Utility classes not working inline but only in CSS file

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

Here is the docs link I tried: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#configuring-source-paths

This is my config file:

```
    module.exports = {
    content: ['./src/**/*.{js, jsx, ts, tsx}', './public/index.html'],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

I have also gone through this answer: [Tailwind utility classes only working in css file and not inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71388074/tailwind-utility-classes-only-working-in-css-file-and-not-inline)

I tried editing the config file like this:

```
    module.exports = {
    content: [
        './src/**/*.{js, jsx, ts, tsx}',
        './public/index.html',
        './src/components/**/*.{html,js,jsx}',
    ],

    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: spaces are not allowed so it should be like this  ```'./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'``` and make sure you have installed deps as suggested [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/framework-guides)

Comment: You probably also want to include your CSS files: `'./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,css}'`.